# Два div высота под экран

Tags: html, css

Надо чтобы два блока div имели одинаковую высоту +под экран.

Как сейчас, (блоки одинаковой высоты+, не под экран-)

```
<style>
 .container {
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-width: 700px;
   max-width: 900px;
   padding: 0 20px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   display: table;}

.containerLeft {
    background-color: #000;
    #padding: 20px;
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    #max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    #padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;}

   .containerRight {
    margin-left: 260px;
    background: #fff;

    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    #box-sizing: border-box;
    #padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;}


</style>
<div class="container">  
    <div class="containerLeft">БЛОК</div>
    <div class="containerRight">БЛОК2</div>
</div>
```

**Без javaScript, table.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "под экран" имеется в виду "по высоте экрана", то можно добавить

```
.containerLeft, .containerRight {
   height: 100%;
}
```

и для .container соответственно

```
.container {
   ...
   height:100%;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Вроде работает, + подправить padding